# Asp.Net Button In Repeater not triggering any action

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have an old ASP.Net User Control with a Repeater that I need to add a button to. The problem I have is that the button doesn't appear to raise any events when clicked, although the page is posted back.

My control looks ( in relevant parts ) like this:

```
<ul id="MemberList">
<asp:Repeater id="MemberRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
            ( <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %> )
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="containerButton" Text="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
                CommandName="EditButtonPressed" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MemberId") %>' />
        </li>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Then in the C# file I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    members = Member.GetAllAsList();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        MemberRepeater.DataSource = members;
        MemberRepeater.DataBind();
        foreach (RepeaterItem itm in MemberRepeater.Items)
        {
            // Tried adding a click event to the Button itself. 
            Button editButton = (Button)(itm.FindControl("containerButton"));
            editButton.Click += editButton_Click;

        }
        // Tried adding an ItemCommand to the repeater.
        MemberRepeater.ItemCommand += MemberRepeater_ItemCommand;
    }
}

void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void MemberRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void EditButtonPressed(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now as far as I can tell, at least *one* of these strategies should work, but none of those exceptions get raised and breakpoints on all three never get hit. It is, however, a while since I have worked in detail with old-fashioned ASP.Net so I wouldn't be surprised if I have forgotten some all-important step in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're binding the event in the code-behind, make sure you are binding it for every request, even when `IsPostback == true`.

If you're binding it in the markup, you need to add the [`OnItemCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on your `Repeater`.

```
<asp:Repeater id="MemberRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="MemberRepeater_ItemCommand">
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `MemberRepeater.ItemCommand += MemberRepeater_ItemCommand`?

Comment: Events need to be hooked up on every page request, including on postbacks.

Comment: I'm sure I knew that at one time. Thanks!